# I keep getting this error: Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am new to R and I am running a script to create clusters for my dataset.

I keep getting the following error: Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

I don't really know what is wrong, the code worked a few times before and I haven't changed anything.

Can you please help me.

Thanks!

Tammy [please click for image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu4PT.png)

I want to create clusters in my map.

Comment: I don't see you defining `sub` anywhere.

Comment: Generally errors with "cannot coerce type 'closure'" mean you are trying to use a function name as if it were an object. `sub()` is the name of a function for doing string substitution. In your function you have `data = sub`, and, as Roland says, it doesn't look like you've defined `sub` anywhere, so probably the only `sub` is the built-in function.

Comment: Thank you both for pointing this out! It works now!